# How can triggered event attributes of injected html tags that reference functions in a content script of a firefox extension be executed?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am building my first firefox extension. The documentation available provided by Mozilla is not very detailed, and the meager examples given do not help to answer my question.

My extension uses a content script to modify a webpage by injecting html tags. Some of these tags have event attributes such as onmouseenter and onmouseleave that reference functions in the content script. However, although the html is successfully injected into web pages, the triggered events give a reference error and so the function does not execute.

```
<span onmouseenter='onMouseEnter(this)'>Hello</span>
```

In my research so far, I think I have discovered a possible problem. The content script lives in a different scope and thus the triggered events can't access the functions in the content script.

```
function onMouseEnter(e){
   alert(e.innerText);
}
```

What can I do to make this work?

```
"content_scripts": [
 {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["js/content_script.js"],
    "css": ["css/style.css"]    
 }
],
```

Comment: Can you attach the listener with Javascript instead of an inline HTML attribute (which are generally considered to be poor practice)?

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance. That is what I needed to do. It is now working. I'll post an example solution so that others in the future seeking an answer will get an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you CertainPerformance for your comment. It led me to the solution.

this is what I did

```
function tester5(){
   var firstelementtags = document.getElementsByClassName(class_tag1);
   for(i=0; i<firstelementtags.length; i++){
       firstelementtags[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseEnter);
   }
   var secondelementtags = document.getElementsByClassName(class_tag2);
   for(j=0; j<secondelementtags.length; j++){
      secondelementtags[j].addEventListener("mousleave", onMouseLeave);
      secondelementtags[j].addEventListener("click", onClick);
   } 
}
```